# Migration não cria tabela no banco de dados. TypeORM, postgreSQL

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Boa noite pessoal.
Neste meu projeto eu estou utilizando o typeorm para configurar o meu banco de dados.
Eu crie a minha migration, porém quando eu executo o comando *yarn typeorm migration:run*, ele não cria a tabela que eu defini.
Ele cria no banco de dados apenas a tabela migrations, a outra tabela 'employee' ele não cria.

*https://github.com/SamuelB7/employee_manager2*

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
export class employees1603488907171 implements MigrationInterface {

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
            name: 'employee',
            columns: [
                {
                    name: 'id',
                    type: 'integer',
                    unsigned: true,
                    isPrimary: true,
                    isGenerated: true,
                    generationStrategy: 'increment',
                },
                {
                    name:'name',
                    type: 'text',
                    isNullable: false
                }
            ]
        }))
    }

    public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.dropTable('employee')
    }

}
```

Comment: Verifica se essa migration já está na sua tabela de migrations, rodar o down dessa migration e depois rodar o up.

Comment: Decidi trocar pelo sequelize, pelo que eu pesquisei, o typeorm é mais voltado para typescript, e nesse projeto que estou desenvolvendo, eu quero usar somente javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Vi que você já trocou o typeORM pelo sequelize, mas segue uma possível solução para esse problema caso alguém mais venha ter.

Lá no arquivo `ormconfig.json` você precisa especificar o local das suas migrations e também para a cli do typeORM, segue um exemplo:

```js
{
  "name": "default",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": <<HOST>>,
  "port": <<PORT>>,
  "username": <<USERNAME>>,
  "password": <<PASSWORD>>,
  "database": <<DATABASE_NAME>>,
  "entities": [
    "./src/models/*.ts"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "./src/database/migrations/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "./src/database/migrations"
  }
}
```